# How to remove last occurrence of OR from string

Tags: php

I just want to ask that I want to remove the last OR from following string.

```
$string = 'b.dates LIKE "2017-10-13%" OR 
b.dates LIKE "2017-10-14%" OR 
b.dates LIKE "2017-10-15%" OR 
b.dates LIKE "2017-10-16%" OR 
b.dates LIKE "2017-10-17%" OR';
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$ character indicates the end of string.

```
preg_replace("/OR$/", '', $str );
```

or

```
rtrim($str, ' OR');
```

Comment: In case someone is wanting to use this solution with user input, please remember to pass that through `preg_quote()` first :)

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
$hello ="dddOR";
echo rtrim($hello,"OR");
?>
```

http://php.net/rtrim

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

[strrpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) -  Find the position of the last occurrence of a substring in a string

```
$string = 'b.dates LIKE "2017-10-13%" OR 
b.dates LIKE "2017-10-14%" OR 
b.dates LIKE "2017-10-15%" OR 
b.dates LIKE "2017-10-16%" OR 
b.dates LIKE "2017-10-17%" OR';    


echo substr_replace($string,'', strrpos($string, 'OR'), 2);
```

OUTPUT:

> b.dates LIKE "2017-10-13%" OR b.dates LIKE "2017-10-14%" OR b.dates
>   LIKE "2017-10-15%" OR b.dates LIKE "2017-10-16%" OR b.dates LIKE
>   "2017-10-17%"

Working Demo: http://codepad.org/rw3q40mk

Answer (score 3):

Removes exactly last 3 chars

```
substr($string, 0, -3);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use built in php **str_replace()** function for removing all the occurance of **OR** from the string as below.

```
$res = str_replace("OR", "",$string);
echo ($res);
```

**Result:**

b.dates LIKE "2017-10-13%"

b.dates LIKE "2017-10-14%"

b.dates LIKE "2017-10-15%"

b.dates LIKE "2017-10-16%"

b.dates LIKE "2017-10-17%"

**To remove last occurance of or use the code below**

```
echo substr($string, 0,strrpos($string,"OR"));
```

**Result**
b.dates LIKE "2017-10-13%" OR b.dates LIKE "2017-10-14%" OR b.dates LIKE "2017-10-15%" OR b.dates LIKE "2017-10-16%" OR b.dates LIKE "2017-10-17%"

for more info visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Read question carefully... I want to remove the last occurrence of OR not all .

Comment: yup that's my fault but i've now updated  for the last occurrence

Comment: it replaces all OR from the string. which is not real question asked by user